# Is AES-CTR or ChaCha20 vulnerable to a time-memory trade off?

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher

Is AES-CTR or ChaCha20 vulnerable to a time-memory trade-off attack?

According to [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/090.pdf) it seems to be, which would put AES-CTR at a clearly breakable $2^{64}$ security level (for AES-128-CTR).  Since AES-128-CTR is not considered breakable something is wrong with this statement and I would like to know what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a concern; the model of costs that the paper uses is unrealistic.  In the paper, they state:

> In other words, the attacker is given unlimited amount
>   of time in preparation

(Section 2, second paragraph)

That is, they assume that the attacker can easily spend $O(2^{128})$ time (or more, if necessary) to generate a Hellman table (or Rainbow table) for AES-128.

Yes, once an attacker does that, he can attack AES-128 (at least, against the plaintext he used while building the rainbow table) faster than he would otherwise.

However, it is generally believed that $O(2^{128})$ effort is infeasible, even as a one-time effort.

Comment: They do take on the question of table generation in the second appendix, where they point to [Lenstra and Verheul](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/164526/files/NPDF-22.pdf) (pdf) for actual numbers.